# Is Magento a Framework or Platform?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

What is magento.. is it a Framework or Platform. Because magento itself uses Zend Framework, but everywhere it's called as a framework.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/tags/magento/info

Comment: Magento is MVC, and has CMS. supported by Zend Framework. until 21-December-2012, i think Magento is the best E-Commerce Platform in this world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento is an e-commerce platform written in PHP atop the Zend framework.

EDIT:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/magento/info

http://www.magentocommerce.com/company/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento

Comment: Still magento zend framework ?  FYI => https://symfony.com/projects  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As per the tag description,

> Magento is an e-commerce **platform** written in PHP atop the Zend framework, available under both open-source and commercial licenses. It is written in an advanced object-oriented idiom that uses the MVC pattern and XML configuration files, aiming for flexibility and extensibility.

As per Wikipedia,

> Magento is an open source ecommerce **web application** that was launched on March 31, 2008. It was developed by Varien (now Magento Inc) with help from the programmers within the open source community but is owned solely by Magento Inc. . Magento was built using the Zend Framework. It uses the entity-attribute-value (EAV) database model to store data.

[Magento Inc.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) itself claims it's a **platform**.

In [google Fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22Magento+framework%22&word2=%22Magento+platform%22), "magento **platform**" wins over "magento framework" 10:1

Answer (score 0):

Magento is an open source ecommerce web application. Magento was built using the Zend Framework.

Here is the link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento

Comment: I believe you've forgotten to link the source.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is an open source E-Commerce CMS.